# Polymer nesting dom-repeat templates multiplicate second template

Tags: javascript, templates, nested, polymer, repeat

I follow the Polymer official example of nesting templates and the second template is repeated.

My array data is similar to this:

```
[
  {
    "title": "My title book",
    "author": "The author",
    "votes": [
      { "bad": 0 },
      { "regular": 2 },
      { "good": 201 },
      { "excellent": 458 } 
    ]
  },
  {
    "title": "My title book",
    "author":"The author",
    "votes": [
      { "bad": 0 },
      { "regular": 2 },
      { "good":201 },
      { "excellent": 458 }
    ]
  }
]
```

and here is my code of polymer element:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{books}}" as="book">
      <div><b>Title: </b><span>{{book.title}}</span></div>
      <div><b>Author: </b><span>{{book.author}}</span></div>
      <div>
        <p>Votes:</p>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{book.votes}}" as="vote">
          <b>Bad: </b><span>{{vote.bad}}</span>
          <b>Regular: </b><span>{{vote.regular}}</span>
          <b>Good: </b><span>{{vote.good}}</span>
          <b>Excellent: </b><span>{{vote.excellent}}</span>
        </template>
      </div>
</template>
```

The result of this is:

Title: My book title 
Author: My author 
Votes: 
Bad: 0 Regular: Good: Excellent: Bad: Regular: 2 Good: Excellent: Bad: Regular: Good: 201 Excellent: Bad: Regular: Good: Excellent: 458

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each element in `book.votes` contains *either* `bad`, `regular`, `good`, *or* `excellent`, but the inner template repeater assumes all voting types are present in each object. That is, the template outputs the tally for all votes in each iteration when only one of those votes is available.

Walking through the four iterations...

1. The repeater reads `book.votes[0]` (`{"bad": 0}`) as `vote`.

   - It reads `vote.bad` and gets a value of `0`.
   - It can't find `vote.regular`.
   - It can't find `vote.good`.
   - It can't find `vote.excellent`.

     Result:

     ```
     Bad: 0 Regular: Good: Excellent:
     ```
2. The repeater reads `book.votes[1]` (`{"regular": 2}`) as `vote`.

   - It can't find `vote.bad`.
   - It reads `vote.regular` and gets a value of `2`.
   - It can't find `vote.good`.
   - It can't find `vote.excellent`.

     Result:

     ```
     Bad: Regular: 2 Good: Excellent:
     ```
3. The repeater reads `book.votes[2]` (`{"good": 201}`) as `vote`.

   - It can't find `vote.bad`.
   - It can't find `vote.regular`.
   - It reads `vote.good` and gets a value of `201`.
   - It can't find `vote.excellent`.

     Result:

     ```
     Bad: Regular: Good: 201 Excellent:
     ```
4. The repeater reads `book.votes[3]` (`{"excellent": 458}`) as `vote`.

   - It can't find `vote.bad`.
   - It can't find `vote.regular`.
   - It can't find `vote.good`.
   - It reads `vote.excellent` and gets a value of `458`.

     Result:

     ```
     Bad: Regular: Good: Excellent: 458
     ```

If the intention is to show all voting tallies at once, `book.votes` should be an object instead of an array of objects:

```
"votes": {
  "bad": 0,
  "regular": 2,
  "good": 201,
  "excellent": 458
}
```

...and the inner template repeater should be removed, binding to `book.votes.*` directly:

```
<div>
  <b>Bad: </b><span>{{book.votes.bad}}</span>
  <b>Regular: </b><span>{{book.votes.regular}}</span>
  <b>Good: </b><span>{{book.votes.good}}</span>
  <b>Excellent: </b><span>{{book.votes.excellent}}</span>
</div>
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-card/paper-card.html">
</head>

<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{books}}" as="book">
        <paper-card>
          <div><b>Title: </b><span>{{book.title}}</span>
          </div>
          <div><b>Author: </b><span>{{book.author}}</span>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>Votes:</p>
            <div>
              <b>Bad: </b><span>{{book.votes.bad}}</span>
              <b>Regular: </b><span>{{book.votes.regular}}</span>
              <b>Good: </b><span>{{book.votes.good}}</span>
              <b>Excellent: </b><span>{{book.votes.excellent}}</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </paper-card>
      </template>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: 'x-foo',
        properties: {
          books: {
            type: Array,
            value: function() {
              return [{
                "title": "My title book",
                "author": "The author",
                "votes": {
                  "bad": 0,
                  "regular": 2,
                  "good": 201,
                  "excellent": 458
                }
              }, {
                "title": "The other book",
                "author": "The other author",
                "votes": {
                  "bad": 11,
                  "regular": 22,
                  "good": 33,
                  "excellent": 44
                }
              }];
            }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

<sup>jsbin [before](http://jsbin.com/guqani/edit?html,output) / [after](http://jsbin.com/qokaqa/edit?html,output)</sup>